# How to update the style of an element on state change

Tags: reactjs

I have a button that changes state when clicked. I would like a style (resultInfo) to show up on another element when the button state is false. I tried to use useEffect [checkAnswer] to update the other element's inline style, but upon the button's state change, the other element's style is not updated. How come the following doesn't work? Thanks.

```
// the Continue button that also shows the user if they are correct or wrong
import React, { useEffect, useContext, useState } from 'react';
import { PracticeContext } from '../contexts/PracticeContext';
import ModuleFinished from './ModuleFinished';

// Enables the user to check their answer, shows the result, and provides an element to proceed to the next question
const ModulePracticeAnswerResult = ( {questionNumber, answer, attempt} ) => {
  const { setShowModuleFinished } = useContext(PracticeContext);
  const { questionIndex, setQuestionIndex } = useContext(PracticeContext);
  const { selectedPracticeEnd } = useContext(PracticeContext);

  const [checkAnswer, setCheckAnswer] = useState(false);

  // create the user selected module for practice
  useEffect(() => {
    setCheckAnswer(false); // answer state is reverted when question state is updated
  }, [questionIndex]);

  // navigate to the next question
  function progress(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    if (checkAnswer === false) {
      setCheckAnswer(true);
      return; 
    }
    if (selectedPracticeEnd === true) {
      // there are no more questions - don't progress any further
      if (checkAnswer) {
        setShowModuleFinished(true);
      }
      return;
    }
    // if checkAnswer is true, user has already answers and received feedback. progress to next question 
    setQuestionIndex(questionNumber + 1);
  }

  let resultInfo = { display: 'none' };

  useEffect(() => {
    // when check answer button has been pressed, its state changes to false until the continue button is pressed
    if (checkAnswer === false) {
      // display the result of the answer
      if (answer === attempt) {
        resultInfo = { display: 'block', background: '#4CAF50' }
      } 
      else {
        resultInfo = { display: 'block', background: 'rgb(255, 52, 86)' }
      }
      return;
    }
    resultInfo = { display: 'none' }; // user hasn't checked the answer yet
  }, [checkAnswer]);

  return (
    <div className="module-practice-answer-result">
      <div className="result-info-container">
        <div style={resultInfo}>
          <p>{ 'result message here...' }</p>
        </div>
        <button 
          className={ checkAnswer === false ? 'answer-button answer-button-default' : 'answer-button answer-button-continue' } 
          onClick={progress} disabled={attempt.length < 1 ? 'disabled' : ''}>
            { checkAnswer === false ? 'Check' : 'Continue' }
        </button>
      </div>

      <ModuleFinished />
    </div>
  );
}

export default ModulePracticeAnswerResult;
```

Comment: Can you add the code for useState, and the handler that changes the state?

Comment: Sure, I've added the whole component

Comment: `useEffect` will be run after first mount or subsequent updates. So when you update your `checkAnswer`, your component will run with the default style in `resultInfo` and  the updated value in `resultInfo` will not be passed on to the component. Try to convert your `resultInfo` to a `state` and try setting it to see your changes.

Comment: Ok, thanks. I didn't realise it would need a state, but I'm getting some action now after using const [resultInfo, setResultInfo] = useState({display:'none'}); The logic is a bit messed up, but I'll fix that.